# How to implement Shinx voice recognition api in android

Tags: android, sphinx, voice-recognition

I want to implement Sphinx voice recognition API in my program that run on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this ,it may be helpful

http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/